# PHP APC uploads are never marked as complete

Tags: php, file-upload, apc, suhosin

I have a LAMP setup running PHP 5.2.6-1 with the Suhosin Patch (0.9.6.2) and Zend (2.2.0) with APC enabled for use with a file upload script using an ajax cal to get the status and generate a progress bar.

Everything appears to be working, the file uploads perfectly and is displayed correctly on the website or if you download it, but it never gets marked as "complete" by APC, nor does the file size reach the actual size (in the APC call, the uploaded file is just fine).

What could be the reason for APC never seeing the file completely uploaded, and how can I solve this? I'm currently running a rather hack'n'slash way for this, since the file size always reaches at least 90%, I've got my ajax call checking the size, if it's at 90% and stays there for 3 updates, it waits 5 more seconds and then expects it to be completed (not ideal if it's a large file and it really isn't done yet)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting apc.rfc1867_freq=0 this should make APC update the size all the way, whereas before it may have been updating it in 10k increments and stopped near the end.

Answer (score -1):

check the upload_max_filesize. If you are trying to upload a file that is bigger than upload_max_filesize then the you will have this problem. Increase the upload_max_filesize to fix the problem.